# OpenstreetMap how to validate post addresses

Tags: java, geocoding, openstreetmap, compass-geolocation, nominatim

I am working on a project where I should develop an application to validate post addresses in Germany, Switzerland and Austria. For that I need to set up a address database with all information. But I don't know where i can get the data. I googled for a long time but I didn't find an answer for my problem.
I have 2 questions:

1. can I work with the rest service of nominatim in a productive environment? the application will process approximately over then 300000 request a day.
2. can I import an openstreetmap file (*.osm) in a DB (MySql) and work with that? ist there all the informations i need to validate addresses. such as streetname exists? housenumber exists? fit street to housenumber and town?

thans in advance

Achraf

Answer (score 6, accepted):

1. Yes, you can use Nominatim in a productive environment. However not
   OSM's public instance (take a look at the [usage policy](http://wiki.openstreetmap.org/wiki/Nominatim_usage_policy) for the
   reasons). Just [install your own Nominatim instance](https://nominatim.org/release-docs/latest/admin/Installation/) or use one of the other [alternatives](https://wiki.openstreetmap.org/wiki/Nominatim_usage_policy#Alternatives_.2F_Third-party_providers).
2. That depends on the exact information you need. Some adress information are implicitly contained (usually address, house number), some others need to be calculated first (often the city, municipality, state, post codes etc.) because they are often not attached to the address elements directly but to [administrative boundary relations](https://wiki.openstreetmap.org/wiki/Tag:boundary%3Dadministrative) instead. Nominatim does all of these processing for you.

Also take a look at other [OSM search engines](http://wiki.openstreetmap.org/wiki/Search_engines). And remember that OSM doesn't contain every possible address.

Comment: hi Scai, Thanks a lot for your answer.

Comment: i have another question. Is there a possibility to download post/address data from another location/organization without using an intermediate project like Nominatim. I only need the data, i will anyway write new software for the validation. at least for germany because we have an contract with german post and they send us a CD with all possible Address data. And because the OSM doesn't contain every possible address its safer for us to work with the CD. for other Countries i need only the data. No matter if they are note complete. thanks

Comment: I'm not familiar with other data sources so I can't really answer your follow-up question.

Comment: @Sami: Contact the Switzerland and Austria postal services and see if they have CDs for sale or distribution.